# Генерация уникальной строки при обновлении и добавлении записи PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Использую в Yii приложении [поведение](https://github.com/baibaratsky/yii2-slug-behavior) для генерации уникального uri записи в базе из заголовка этой записи. При создании записи, текст из поля name превращается в транслит, разделенный дефисами. 
Если строка получилась не уникальной, в конец строки добавляется порядковый номер данной строки. Т.е. при добавлении трех записей с name='любой текст' получим последовательно 'luboy-tekst', 'luboy-tekst-1', 'luboy-tekst-2'.
 
К сожалению, в рамках архитектуры не удастся контролировать заполнение поля uri в таблицах, потому генерацию этого значения придется сделать на уровне бд. Насколько я понимаю, в вышеупомянутом поведении используется php-intl. Есть ли какие-то инструменты у postgress для данной задачи?

Comment: *К сожалению, в рамках архитектуры не удастся контролировать заполнение поля uri в таблицах, потому генерацию этого значения придется сделать на уровне бд* - используйте оптимистичную блокировку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи исключительно на стороне базы данных Вам определенно необходимо воспользоваться триггерами. В Вашем случае необходимо создать триггер, который будет выполняться до (или вместо) добавления записи. Пример создания триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUriTrigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON uriTable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trUriProcedure();
```

Реализовать же Ваш триггер нужно по следующему принципу:

- Траслитеризация записи с помощью метода translate. Пример использования
  ``` translate(lower(field_value, 'абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхць', 'abvgdeezijklmnoprstufхc``')) ```
- Проверка полученной записи на уникальность. Если проверка пройдена - добавляем запись как есть
- Если проверка не пройдена, необходимо либо создать новую последовательность с именем равным транслитерованному тексту, если последовательность была не создана, либо получить новый номер из уже созданной последовательностью

Пример создания последовательности:
`CREATE SEQUENCE transliteratedURI START 1;`
Пример получения нового числа из последовательности: 
`SELECT nextval('generatedUriId');`
К тому же Вам придется воспользоваться Dynamic SQL чтобы динамически задавать имя для последовательности. Пример:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
const char *stmt = "CREATE SEQUENCE ? START 1;";
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;    
EXEC SQL EXECUTE mystmt USING transliteratedURI;
```

где в transliteratedURI должен храниться транслитеризованый текст
[Подробнее о триггерах в PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.ru.net/docs/trigger.html).
[Подробнее о последовательностях в PostgreSQL](http://doc.artofweb.ru/doc/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_PostgreSQL).
[Подробнее о динамическом SQL в PostgreSQL](https://www.postgrespro.ru/doc/ecpg-dynamic.html).

Comment: Если Вы всё же настаиваете на отдельной нумерации для каждой страницы, то тогда можете создавать отдельную последовательность для каждого URI.

Comment: В таком случае мне проще прибавить id к транслиту от name, который даже записывать в бд не нужно, потому что ничто не помешает генерить его на лету. Но я хочу именно уйти от числовой нумерации. Дубликатов uri будет совсем мало, потому цифры будут встречаться редко. Но я еще не нашел способа сделать это на стороне бд.

Comment: @ilyaplot Создайте триггер ДО добавления записи, в котором проверяйте уникальность, если URI будет не уникален - создавайте последовательность, если же она уже создана - вызывайте для неё nextval

Comment: Ок, с этим понятно, но как быть с самим транслитом?

Comment: @ilyaplot Поправил ответ чтобы более целостно ответить на Ваш вопрос